# How do i aggregate data from a table to show the sum of products based on the category using each month as key

Tags: php, mysql, sql, rdbms

```
create table products
    (
        id int not null,
        productname varchar(45),
        productcategory varchar(45),
        productprice decimal(8,2),
        datepurchased varchar(45),
        primary key (id)
    );

 INSERT INTO products (id, productname, productcategory, productprice, datepurchased) VALUES
 (1, 'Toy car', 'toys', 200.30, '2017 December'),
  (2, 'Phone', 'phone', 50.00, '2017 December'),
  (3, 'Disk drive', 'Accessories', 10.00, '2018 January'),
   (4, 'Mouse', 'Accessories', 20.30, '2018 January'),
   (5, 'Baby doll', 'toys', 100.00, '2018 February'),
    (6, 'Toy car', 'toys', 40.10, '2018 March');
```

My sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff0cf/1/0
The results should look like this.

```
Month           |  ProductCategory    | Amount
-------------------------------------------------
2017 December   |  toys               | 200.30
2018 January    |  phone              |  50.00
2018 January    |  Accessories        |  30.30
2018 February   |  toys               |  100.00
2018 March      |  toys               |   40.10
```

If you notice, Accessories has multiple entries for January and it is summed.

Please include a sql fiddle in your answer if you can. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff0cf/15/0

What you want is to do a group by with multiple params:

```
SELECT id, productcategory, sum(productprice), datepurchased FROM
products GROUP BY productcategory, datepurchased;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select datepurchased month, productcategory, sum(productprice) amount
from products
group by datepurchased, productcategory
order by datepurchased, amount desc;
```

See a working [DEMO on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff0cf/23).

Answer (score 0):

As datepurchased column isn't a DATE, or a DATETIME column, then it needs to be manipulated by using a certain string functions.

Here's your answer, I hope it helps you. Any issue, let me know, please.

```
    SELECT
      cte._month
      , cte.productcategory
      , SUM(cte.productprice) AS totalPrice
    FROM (
            SELECT
                id
                ,productname
                ,productcategory
                ,productprice
                ,CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(datepurchased, ' ', 1) AS UNSIGNED) AS _year
                ,TRIM(SUBSTRING(datepurchased, POSITION(' ' IN datepurchased), (LENGTH(datepurchased) - 
                            LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(datepurchased, ' ', 1)))
                            )) AS _month
            FROM products
    ) AS cte
    GROUP BY cte._month, cte.productcategory;
```

SQL Fiddle URL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4ff0cf/43